# how to catch ip and mac id and display in a label in windows form

Tags: windows, winforms, performance, winforms-interop

1>just want a small windows form in which it will catch the ip and mac id and display too the user in the label .
2> is how to ping between the client and server using windows form.
3>how to use wpfinteroperability in windows form best uses of the wpf in windows form

Comment: This sounds like homework right?

Comment: nope steve sir its for my knowledge only

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP, using something like this:

```
public static string GetExternalIP()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string strIP = wc.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
            strIP = (new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b")).Match(strIP).Value;
            wc.Dispose();
            return strIP;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And to get MAC adress you can do something like:

```
public static string GetMacAdress()
    {
        try
        {

            var macAddr = (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                           where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                           select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

            return macAddr;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

About interoperability, you should take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37360/Winforms-WPF-Interop)